# How to log stack trace using log4net (C#)

Tags: c#, log4net

How to log stack trace with `log4net`? I am using `.Net` version.

They way I have is `Log.Error(ex)`.

Thanks

Comment: Are you having a particular problem with the output of Log.Error(ex)?

Answer (score 30):

Use this:

```
void Error(object message,Exception t)
```

Reason is in log4net documentation for `void Error(object message)`:

> WARNING Note that passing an Exception to this method will print the name of the Exception but no stack trace. To print a stack trace use the `void Error(object,Exception)` form instead.

`Error(object message, Exception t)` is the most flexible way to log exception data because it goes as an Exception rather than Object and that can be used in appenders to narrow logs to a particular exception class (rather than by searching for a string which is much slower and less consistent)

There are special versions of all non-format logging methods that take message and exception:

```
namespace log4net
{
    public interface ILog
    {
        ...
        /* Log a message object and exception */
        void Debug(object message, Exception t);
        void Info(object message, Exception t);
        void Warn(object message, Exception t);
        void Error(object message, Exception t);
        void Fatal(object message, Exception t);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to ensure that the definition of the layout pattern is structured to output what format and data you want.

[log4Net Pattern Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout.htm)

> Used to output the stack trace of the logging event The stack trace level specifier may be enclosed between braces. For example, **%stacktrace{level}.** If no stack trace level specifier is given then 1 is assumed

Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3 > type2.MethodCall2 > type1.MethodCall1

This pattern is not available for Compact Framework assemblies.

Comment: What does the level 1 indicate? I don't see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 12):

There are two basic forms, one that takes an object and an exception explicitly:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // the form that takes two args has an exception as second, prints trace...
    _log.Error("My custom message", ex);
}
```

And one that takes any object and performs a `ToString()` on it:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // the form that takes one arg uses ToString()
    _log.Error(ex);
}
```

The former allows you to attach a more meaningful message on the log entry first to give any additional detail you'd like.  The latter will do the job but only prints the exception details using `ToString()`, which gives you:

> The default implementation of ToString obtains the name of the class
>   that threw the current exception, the message, the result of calling
>   ToString on the inner exception, and the result of calling
>   Environment.StackTrace. If any of these members is Nothing, its value
>   is not included in the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the ILog to have a  method that logs just an exception with his stack trace.

```
public static void ErrorWithStackTrace(this ILog log, Exception exception)
 {
    log.Error(exception.Message,exception);
   }
```

Comment: Why not to use the existing ILog implementation which supports this already ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Logger SetIfNeededAndGetLogger(string serviceName, string methodName)
{
    Logger logger = null;

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serviceName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(methodName))
        {
            ILog log = null;
            var traceSourceName = string.Format("{0}{1}", serviceName, methodName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(traceSourceName))
            {
                logger = LogSources.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceLogType == traceSourceName);
                if (logger == null)
                {
                    log = LogManager.GetLogger(traceSourceName);
                    //logger = new Logger(log, IHEService.MediLogClientGuid, traceSourceName, methodName);
                    logger = new Logger(log, System.Guid.NewGuid(), traceSourceName, methodName);
                    SetLoggingSource(logger);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //silent faiure
    }

    return logger;
}

private static void SetLoggingSource(Logger value)
{
    LogSources.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.